# select files with name contains a character php

Tags: php, regex

So i want to select the image that has **-bpfull** in name, like this **5ac46ae912feaaf004b2fdb88f1c8a1a-bpfull.png** .

I have a lot of images and i want a regex to do it, this is my small code to select images from the folder :

```
$dir = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/avatars/2/';
```

so plz if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attempt is shown to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use phps glob() function

```
foreach (glob($dir . "*-bpfull.*") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename . "\n";
}
```